# Splitting my Webpack bundle is causing JS issues

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using Webpack in a fairly simple, straightforward way that bundles together a few JS and TS files into one bundle, and it works well on my site.

However, I want to split the current bundle into smaller bundles, as I get both a warning when I build the bundle due to it's size, and I get warnings running Lighthouse audits in browser that I should reduce the file size of my bundle.js file.

The simplest solution in my mind is to split my current bundle into 4 parts, i.e. bundle1.min.js, bundle2.min.js, etc... Then I just serve the bundles consecutively.

The problem is splitting and serving my bundle this way is breaking other JS on my page. For example a function defined in bundle1 and called in a different JS file no longer works, unless I remove all the other bundle.js files. It seems that only the most recently loaded bundle file works.

Is there a better approach to get smaller bundles, and make sure that all bundles work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Route-based code splitting is quite popular because each page/route usually has a small subset of components on it.

The guide can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#route-based-code-splitting) (for React)

Answer (score 0):

A little embarrassed, looks like this was just a scoping issue with a dependency in one bundle breaking code in another by being absent. Reorganizing my bundles so dependencies are present where needed. Ai ya.